# What does a Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate LoadTest run on?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, load-testing

Pretty much, I am needing to know if I need to run it on a server or can it be run from my desktop?  I would hate to think I would run a 24 hour load test from my desktop and tie up my machine, but is that how it goes?  Or can I run it from a server (virtual or other?)?

Sorry for the ambiguity, but I do not know much about the infrastructure needed to run this.  I tried researching it but all I can find is how to run a load test, not the physical requirements.  I also read something about team systems.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirements are in MSDN, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff937706.aspx). And yes, you can run it on your desktop. As you will see from the link, your requirements are driven by the number of virtual users you want to add to the load. How resource intensive your tests are also plays into this.

You should be able to find what you need on MSDN. Read though it and set things up and run the test. Post a more specific question here on StackOverflow if you run into problems.